# How do I programmatically remove menu tabs from the user login page?

Tags: 8, routes

In Drupal 7 I could remove tabs using hook_menu_alter() like below:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu_alter
*/
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {  
  $items['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/login']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/password']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;  
}
```

This hook has been removed from D8 and is now handled by altering routes. However, I cannot figure out how to remove the these tabs from the user login page. The following page gave examples of altering a menu item's title and permissions, but I haven't been able to find any clues to remove a tab from a page.

https://dev.acquia.com/blog/coding-drupal-8/defining-and-altering-routes-in-drupal-8/22/03/2016/9891

Comment: `The following page` where is the link?